# Hi I need a gridview which have 2 different layout in grid cells according to diffenrenrt grid cell type.here is I am giving the example screen

Tags: android, view, grid

[please check image from hear](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KxzN8.jpg) 
Hi I need a gridview which have 2 different layout in grid cells according to diffenrenrt  grid cell type.here is I am giving the example screen

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use recyclerView as gridview as well.In recyclerview you can have different type of view holder based on some condition.

for different type of view holder based on condition you can check:

https://guides.codepath.com/android/Heterogenous-Layouts-inside-RecyclerView

Comment: thnks.u r saving my lots of time